# Как закрыть модальное окно после отправки письма?

Tags: javascript

Вот сам скрипт

```
   $(function(){
    /* Mail */
    $('.mail').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).find('.phone').val().trim().length > 0){
        $(this).children('.sends').replaceWith("<h5 class='nomargbut tcenter'>Спасибо за заявку!</h5><h5 class='nomargbut tcenter'>Мы свяжемся с Вами в течение 30 минут</h5>");
        $(this).children('.send').replaceWith("<h5 class='nomargbut tcenter'>Спасибо за заявку!</h5><h5 class='nomargbut tcenter'>Мы свяжемся с Вами в течение 30 минут</h5>");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'sends.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "true"){
                    $('.back, .hide').hide().before('<div class="success">Success text.</div>');
                    setTimeout("$('.success').fadeOut()", 3000);
                }
            }
        });
        } else {
            alert('empty field');
        }
    });
```

Как закрыть модальное окно после его выполнения?

```
  <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal tcenter">
    <h2>Оставьте заявку</h2>
            <p>Оставьте заявку и наши<br>
менеджеры с вами свяжутся</p>
            <div class="form-wrap3 tcenter">
                <form action="" class='mail' method='POST'>
                    <input id="name" maxlength="200" name="name" required type="text"  placeholder='Введите имя' pattern='^[А-Яа-яЁё\s]{2,}'  title="Введите ваше имя русскими буквами" pattern='[А-Яа-яЁё]{2,}'><br>
                            <input class="phone" maxlength="20" name="phone" type="text" placeholder='Ваш телефон' pattern='8[0-9]{10}' required title="Формат (с цифры 8 и без пробелов): 89061111111" ><br>
                            <button class="sends" type="submit"></button>
                            <input type=hidden name=mail value="Заявка">
                            <?php include 'hfost.php'; ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="znachenie" value="Заказ звонка"></form>

            </div>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: как думаете, удобно будет отвечающему использовать ваш код с '>' ?

Comment: А я б за "Формат (с цифры 8 и без пробелов)" - по рукам линейкой :)

Comment: и за `setTimeout("$('.success').fadeOut()",3000)`

Comment: поправил, извините

Comment: да нам-то что, это ваши юзеры материться будут...

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myModal').hide();
```

Т.е. мы ищем модальное окно по селектору (`css`) и применяем на нем `jQuery` метод [hide()](http://в), тем самым скрывая модальное окно.

Comment: success: function(data){
                if(data == "true"){
                   $('#myModal').hide();
                }

я так делал, ни в какую

Comment: она исчезает, но $(this).children('.sends') не срабатывает

Comment: А что в `data` приходит, строка `'true'`?

Comment: да, неправильно так?

Answer (score -1):

вставь `data-dismiss="modal"` в тэг кнопки

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Уже пробывал добавлять data-dismiss="modal" но это не помогло

Answer (score -1):

Помогло location.reload(), перезагрузить страничку. Но правильно ли это? На данном этапе эта страница не добавлена в проект SPringBoot, после добавления будет ли это работать и не будет требовать повторную авторизацию?